# LOVE2D: Scale (zoom) to/from point (cursor)

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to describe camera movement in LOVE2D. I followed mostly [this](https://gist.github.com/BlackBulletIV/961685) code, which is some basic camera movement. I struggle, however, to implement zooming to a point (mouse cursor for example).

Scaling works by multiplying everything by a given factor (for x and y axis) which causes all objects to "slide" to the side. Changing the `love.graphics.scale()` function is beyond my capabities so as a workaround I tried to offset the slide by camera movement but it didn`t work.

Is there a way to have a zoom to point functionality in LOVE2D?

Comment: you need a question to get an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`love.graphics.scale` scales from the origin: (0, 0). To scale around the mouse position, you'll want to do a `love.graphics.translate` with minus the mouse position, before scaling. (Depending on how complicated your stuff is, you might need some other corrections, but I really don't know with this little information you gave us.)